# Does every primitive digraph have a directed cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

A **digraph** is a directed graph.

A **directed cycle** or **simple directed circuit** is a directed circuit in which the only repeated vertices are the first and last vertices.

A **digraph is primitive** if its adjacency matrix is primitive.

A square non-negative **matrix** $A$  is said to be **primitive** if there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $A^k >0$ (all entries of $A^k$ are positive).

Comment: What is $T$ in primitive matrix definition?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I had a mistake. It's now corrected.

Comment: Do we allow the graph to have loops? Or do we consider the loops to be directed cycles?

Comment: Simultaneously cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/q/369465 .

Comment: Thanks for the information Emil, it will not happen again.

Comment: Thanks Niko I need only the existence of a path with the structure $i_0 i_1...i_k i_0$ (sequence of distinc edges) with $k\geq 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interpret $(A^n)_{i,j}$ as the number of paths with length $n$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.

Since we have $A^k>0$, we also have, for $n\in\mathbb N$, that $A^{nk}>0$.

Therefore, we can find paths of arbitrary length in the graph, so it must contain a cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact, $A^ k > 0$ for $n\geq k$, this guarantees the existence of paths of any length $ l \geq k $ that connect any two vertices, but no arbitrary length. I need   a path $i_0 i_1 ... i_k i_0$ of distinct symbols with $k\geq 1$

Comment: Since you're not given an explicit graph, you can't get an explicit path. However, you can say that the graph has $|V|$ nodes, therefore any path of length $n>|V|$ has to contain at least one vertex twice.  Therefore the path contains a directed cycle.

Comment: Thanks but I need only the existence of a path with the structure $i_0 i_1...i_k i_0$ (sequence of distinc edges) with $k\geq 1$.

Comment: That's precisely what my previous comment implies

Comment: But perhaps the paths of length $n>|V|$ are generated with loops... I wonder if it is always possible that $i_1\neq i_2\neq \cdots \neq i_k$... in $i_0 i_1...i_k i_0$...

Comment: Let $p = v_1\to v_2\to...\to v_n$ be a path in the graph, where $v_1,...,v_n$ are nodes of the graph. Let $v_k$ be the first node to reappear, and let $v_k = v_i$ (for some $i<k$). Then we have that $v_i,..,v_{k-1}$ are all distinct nodes, therefore $v_j\to v_{j+1}$ for $j\in \{i,...,k-1\}$ are also distinct edges.

Comment: Thak you very much. I was worried about the existence of loops but they do not contribute anything in terms of advancing along the path. For our purposes one can suppose even without loss of generality that these do not exist ......Excellent¡¡